# Usage of "Opt": opt vs opt for

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, word-difference

I understand the usage of *opt to* (do something) and *opt out* (of something), but I'm a little confused about *opt* vs *opt for*. For example:

> Which Subjects did you _____?
>   I _____ philosophy; he, however, was thinking of ______ criminology.

What is the correct usage in the above sentences, *opt* or *opt for*?

Comment: Did you invent that example yourself?

Comment: Yes; I saw many people I know using 'opt' in the same context, but it did not sound right, so I asked here.

Answer (score 1):

You opt in /out of something. [receive ads online for something, for example]

You opt **to do** something.

**Opt for** is somewhat **awkward**. And can sound quite unidiomatic.

**What subjects did you opt to take**? Where **opt** means **to choose**.

**He opted to take criminology**.  **for** just would not be used in a sentence like that.

If you absolutely must use opt for, it has to be followed by a noun:

**to opt for criminology; to opt for philosophy.**

It is not elegant.

> This might be a typical exchange using **opt for**:
>
> John: Well, there is always criminology or philosophy
>    Mary: Yes, I
>   opted for criminology.

That said: Which subjects did you opt for? *would not be a usual way to express choices about subjects to be chosen for a course of study.*

It would be used to confirm a person's choice in a situation that is presented to that person. Also, **opt for** has to be following by a noun in this kind of usage.

Comment: The preposition *for* most definitely collocates with *opt* (and it's therefore misleading to say it's awkward – perhaps in a specific context, but that's not mentioned in your answer. Feel free to inspect [these examples](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=77688342) (COCA). See also user Lorel C.'s answer above.

Comment: @userr2684291 It may collocate, yes. But here one would not say: I opted for criminology. And the question: Which subjects did you opt for? would not generally be expressed like that by a native speaker going to university.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean, but no one's saying *opt for* is intended with the meaning "chose for a course of study" **absent any context**. In the right context, say, *A: I had to choose between math, physics, and biology. B: So, which subject did you opt for? A: I went with math.*, I don't think it should necessarily be unidiomatic (it simply means "choose" there).

Comment: @userr2684291 Please read Lorel C's answer. She also says it is clumsy. Why pick on me?

Comment: I'm not picking on anyone, and they say it's only clumsy because it's repeated twice: "In the second sentence, **using that expression twice sounds a little clumsy** though. One of those *opt for*s could be replaced by a form of 'to choose', which means exactly the same thing."

Comment: @userr2684291 It makes no difference at all how many times *opt for* is used in this context; it remains awkward when even used once. *Opt for* isn't something that should be used here; even if it is *syntactically* sound, it's unidiomatic. I have only heard *opt for* used in the context of *I opted for the former* or *I opted for the latter*, which seem to be set phrases.

Comment: Thank you Jason. I feel rescued. :)

Comment: This is harder than I thought.

Answer (score 1):

To my ears, "opt" always needs a preposition after it.

Looking for exceptions, I hit on [this article](https://lingohelp.me/preposition-after-verb/opt-for-out-into-to-in/), which purports to list the prepositions which can follow "opt", in order of frequency. The most common is "for" followed by "out", "into", "to", and "in".

Of course the one you choose (or "**opt for**") depends on your specific circumstance.

In your examples (where the thing to be selected is a simple noun), "opt for" is appropriate.

> Which Subjects did you **opt for**?
>
> I **opted for** philosophy; he, however, was thinking of **opting for** criminology.

In the second sentence, using that expression twice sounds a little clumsy though. One of those **opt for**s could be replaced by a form of "to choose", which means exactly the same thing. Something like:

> I **chose** philosophy; he, however, was thinking of **opting for** criminology.

But "opt" without any preposition (as in: "Which subjects did you **opt**?") is not idiomatic.

Comment: The problem for me is the question: Which subjects did you opt for? Who would even say that? One would say: Which subjects did you choose? Which subjects have you chosen?